# Identify an insect (beetle?)

Tags: species-identification, entomology

- Body size: 30mm
- Location: Poland, in the middle of a large meadow
- It was flying and landed directly on my cap :-)

After consulting wikipedia it look similar to some of [Tenebrionoidea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenebrionoidea) but can't find an exact match.

Help!

[image: unknown insect]
[image: unknown insect]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Buprestid beetle, and I think the species is *Chalcophora mariana*. It doesn't look all that coppery in your photos, but the large size and shape is perfect. Their larvae live mostly on pines, so perhaps there were pines close to your meadow? [image] ([Image from Wikipedia](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miedziak_sosnowiec))

Comment: (Also I feel a need to say that it's gorgeous and that I'm jealous, they are extremely rare in Sweden so I'll probably never see one)

Comment: Perfect match, thank you! And yes, there are pine forests nearby. In the real life it also looked quite gray, like in my photos, with only a slight brownish/coppery tint. I hope you will meet your Chalcophora mariana some day :-)